# Cannot connect to MySQL on localhost using JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm unable to connect to a MySQL instance running on my own machine, but I don't understand enough about the situation to diagnose the issue.

```
public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tmlschedule";
    
    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pass");
   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}
```

The call to `.getConnection()` throws with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main"
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
Could not create connection to database server.     at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)  at
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)  at
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)   at
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)   at
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)   at
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
    at
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2306)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:839)    at
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)  at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:421)  at
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:350)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)    at
tmlSchedule.MySQLAccess.readDataBase(MySQLAccess.java:22)   at
tmlSchedule.TmlSchedule.main(TmlSchedule.java:9) Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException  at
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3281)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1940)
    at
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1866)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)    at
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2488)
    at
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2521)
    ... 14 more
```

What I've done so far:

- Confirm table name, user name, and password. I can use all these variables to log in to the mysql shell (`mysql -u user -p`) and run select & insert commands.
- Replace the username and password with the login details for the root user on the mysql instance.
- Reference mysql-connector-java.jar in the Java Build Path menu on Eclipse
- Add `mysql` as a trusted service via the GUI for firewalld.
- Running the code with the firewall disabled (`sudo systemctl stop firewalld`). This made no difference.
- Check that mysql is listening on port 3306. `sudo netstat -tuplen` includes the following entry:
  `tcp6   0   0 :::3306   :::*   LISTEN   27   113879   7224/mysqld`

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I'm getting very confused trying to figure out versioning on MySQL and the driver.

`$ zipgrep 'Bundle-Version' /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar` returns:

> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:Bundle-Version: 5.1.25`

`$ mysql --version` returns:

> mysql Ver 8.0.12 for  Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

This suggests that the driver is out of date, but I installed MySQL via the yum repo listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/), which I would imagine would provide me with a driver to match the database. I also tried to install the Connector/J 8.0 via the rpm package listed [here](http://%60https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/%60), but I get the following message, which just doesn't make sense to me:

> package mysql-connector-java-1:5.1.25-3.el7.noarch (which is newer
> than mysql-connector-java-8.0.12-1.el7.noarch) is already installed

Comment: Is the JDBC driver version same as that of the database version?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2310289

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database, say, from the command prompt?

Comment: The issue is with the `NullPointerException` with the character encoding, as shown in the Exception trace. As @prasad_ noted, could be due to version mismatch (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137173/exception-in-connection-with-mysql-through-jdbc). Could also try appending the character encoding to the connect url.

Comment: What is this? `private Connection connection = null;`

Comment: @prasad_ Nice catch. Sorry about that. That's an artifact of me simplifying the actual code a bit (moved a class declaration into the method to keep it more concise).

@ everyone else, thanks for your comments so far. I'll be going through them in a couple of minutes!

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for tipping me off to the version mismatch. Since you were the first one to mention that as the likely culprit, I'd like to mark yours as the chosen answer. Care to post a proper answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application may not be able to connect to a database due to many reasons. One of them is not using a correct driver software (aka JDBC driver).

In this case verifying the usage of the jdbc driver version compatible with the database server itself solved the issue.

One can get a correct driver software from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

One can verify the MySQL server version from command prompt: first, start a MySQL client and from there use the command `mysql> select version();`

Comment: I've added a bit more to the original question, but for some reason I had an old version of the mysql-connector-java installed on my system, and rpm refused to acknowledge that version 8 was more recent than version 5. I ended up uninstalling (`$ sudo yum remove mysql-connector-java`) and then reinstalling it explicitly (`$ sudo yum install mysql-connector-java-8.0.12-1.el7`). Together with Cherokee's answer below, this solved the issue.

Comment: There is no direct correlation between the MySQL Server version and the required JDBC driver version.

Comment: @garroad_ran You really should not be using yum for Java dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see exactly what is happening with the provided code, however, when you build a data access object, you may want to consider building it in such a way that your Connection is a variable of your class, instead of the class's method.

Furthermore, often times by default a mysql database will expect a secure connection. To remove this default, take a look at the url variable.

```
public class DataAccessExample {

private Connection connection;
private final String driverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tmlschedule?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
private final String userName = "YOUR USERNAME";
private final String password = "YOUR PASSWORD";

//Consider calling this openConnection();
public void readDataBase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(driverClass);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
}

//Then have a close connection, this will make your life easier in the future
public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

}

To use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataAccessExample d = new DataAccessExample();

    try {
        d.readDataBase();
        d.closeConnection();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataAccessExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Finally, make sure your database name is correctly spelled and that your username and password are correct.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good stuff all around. Most of what you pointed out was a result of me condensing the code so that it would be as small as possible, but I'll be sure to heed your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that your driver version is too old if your mysql version is 8.x,the driver class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated.The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
The following code comes from the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)：

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

Connection conn = null;
...
try {
    conn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                                   "user=minty&password=greatsqldb");

    // Do something with the Connection

    ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! As soon as I was able to get the proper version of the driver installed, your suggestion made it work instantly. I ended up choosing prasad_'s answer simply because he tipped me off to version mismatching first, but your answer also saved the day!