# unable to create connection to database server and unable to creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: mysql, spring, maven

Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(Interconnection)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3309)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    ... 86 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137173/exception-in-connection-with-mysql-through-jdbc check this

Comment: it's working; thank you.